# Any tutorial, example or experience about using XA Transaction?

Tags: transactions, jms, hornetq, xa

Any tutorial, example or experience about using XA Transaction with two resources: jms broker (HornetQ) and database (using HibernateDaoSupport)?

I have two scenario (I want transaction rollback, if any resource operations failed):

1)

1. Make a message
2. Save it in DB
3. Send it to a queue A

2)

1. Receive a message from queue B
2. Process the message
3. If process succeed, update DB

Answer (score 1):

For tutorial,Google the book "javatransactionsbook.pdf",It includes most of the concept about XA,maybe helpful for you!

Comment: The book mentioned in this answer is "Java Transaction Design Strategies" by Keith Richards, and the URL for that book is http://www.infoq.com/books/JTDS, where the free online version can be downloaded from.